# How to stick to an anchor with svelte?

Tags: anchor, svelte

I have a svelte component that display a list of items, the item list is exported and can be updated outside the component. Usually the list is long and there is a vertical scrollbar on the container `<div>`.

```
<script>
export let items = [];

export let function stickTo(item) {
    // What to write here?
}
</script>

<div id="container">
    {#each items as item}
    <div id="{item.anchor}">...</div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

I would like to scroll the container to a given item, and then stick to it even if the item list is updated. The idea is that all items can appear or disappear anywhere in the list, but the selected item should always stay at the same place on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a svelte action to perform that.
You'd have to keep some kind of "temp array" that would store the old values of "items".
Everytime items would get updated, you would find the new value that's been added by comparing the two arrays.
Of course, if you do have some kind of communication between your components, using context or store, the temp array is not relevant.

Since all your div have ids, I guess you could retrieve the height of the element that has just been added by doing a `getElementById(newElementId).getBoundingClientRect().height`

Then you'd just have to apply a scrollTo to your node (that has been passed by the svelte action). The Y value would be equal to the current scrollTop + your new element's height, the X would be 0.
Still you'd need to be careful not to update the scroll if the element has been placed after your selected item element in the items array.

Maybe I did not understand what you want to do, but I'd go for something like this. Here is an REPL :

https://svelte.dev/repl/bb45f0487f7f4a43af58fb3b861c19ec?version=3.38.2